# Trouble getting NuGet to work on XP

Tags: windows-xp, nuget

I have Powershell 2 installed on the box.
I can run ISE and load modules. The command test-path PathAndFileName works fine.
The box is 64bit running 32bit XP Pro SP3 with VS2008 and VS2010 Premium edition loaded.
I installed the Nov8 version of Nuget using the .vsix.
I have downloaded the NuGet Command Line Tool.

When I try and open a “Add Library Package Reference” no packages are listed. 
I can open the package manager console as Scott Hanselman showed off in PDC 2010.
I can type “list” press the tab key and it auto fills List-Package.

I read some articles about deleting previous copies however I do not think that is the issue. I have read where there was a “package” directory at the same level as the solution file. I do not have one.
I have read where the feed from CP1 has changed for CP2. I deleted all my feeds and added one called MicroDefault with a url of http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=204820.  The url is from the NuGet download page.

The problem is when I execute List-Package I get the following.

```
PM> List-Package
Get-Package : Expected an absolute, well formed http URL without a query or fragment.
Parameter name: serviceRoot
At line:1 char:13
+ List-Package <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.GetPackageCmdlet
```

Any further clues or hints would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing it was the advice in this link. At first I thought it was getting my IT to lower the firewall settings this proved to be incorrect.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/02/downloading-a-local-nuget-repository-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know that NuGet had a problem with Reflector plug-in for Visual Studio.  Downloading the latest Reflector plug-in should fix the problem.

Also you can check out this [article that tells how to create a package](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/baby-steps-to-create-nuget-package/).

Answer (score 0):

When you open the dialog, it shows the list of *Installed* packages by default. Did you click on the Online tab?

The official OData feed is located at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

Also, be sure to visit our Known Issues page: http://nuget.codeplex.com/documentation?title=Known%20Issues

WinXP doesn't have PowerShell 2.0 installed by default. You'll need to make sure that's installed.

Comment: per the marked answer, the Firewall was blocking the ability to see the packages. So lowering the block was the fix.